# BIND/DNS Zone meaning of "IN"

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, syntax

I have been reading http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-bind-zone.html but the document raised a question. What is the meaning of IN? Is it just a class which is optional or does it mean more than that?

(Yes I read that in named.conf IN is a class statement but I don't know if the same applies to the zone files)

I understand that if I don't define a class "IN" in the named.conf zone statement then I don't have to use it either in the zone files like for example:

***With class statement***

*named.conf*

```
zone "example.com" IN {   

file "example.com.zone";   

};
```

*example.com.zone*

```
server1 IN  A   10.0.1.5        
server2 IN  A   10.0.1.6
```

***Without class statement***

*named.conf*

```
zone "example.com" {   

file "example.com.zone";   

};
```

*example.com.zone*

```
server1 A   10.0.1.5        
server2 A   10.0.1.6
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In BIND's zone file as well as in named.conf, IN is a class.

You can omit it in **any** of the files or in **both**, in any case if class is not explicitly specified, the default "**IN**" is used.

Regarding the meaning of "IN" - [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) section 3.2.4:

```
The following CLASS mnemonics and values are defined:

IN              1 the Internet
...
```

Comment: +1 for pointing to the definition source. "Back in the day" there were other classes besides IN, but they're basically all dead.

Answer (score 5):

Always thought it means *Internet Number*. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) is actually just *Internet*:

```
The CLASS of a record is set to IN (for Internet) for common DNS records involving
Internet hostnames, servers, or IP addresses.
```